# "Leave" and "leave for", what's the difference?

Tags: prepositions, difference

I've never used the extra preposition "for" before, i.e. usually I write like this:

1. I leave the house.
2. I'll leave my class in 10 minutes.
3. We have to leave the art gallery.

Recently, I'm using an app to learn English and introduced the sentence with the preposition "for" which is the first time for me to see such a construction. I looked up in the dictionary and it's true that there are two options to use this word, **leave for something** and **leave something**.

What makes it difference if I put "for" after "leave" in those sentences?

1. I leave for the house.
2. I'll leave for my class in 10 minutes.
3. We have to leave for the art gallery.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

“leave” can mean to go away from some place designated by the object.

> I leave home

means

> I go out of or away from my home

“leave for” means to go toward some place designated by the object.

> I leave for home

means

> I leave some undesignated  place in order to go to my home.

Comment: *A leaves B for C*, if B is a person, group, or workplace, can mean A terminated his/her relationship with B so that he/she could start a new relationship with C.

Comment: @DialFrost I agree with you, and it's not an insult, it's a compliment.

Comment: @barbecue Oh, I did not view DialFrost’s comment as intended as an insult, nor did I perceive it as such. I merely think that many respond here with great effort to be helpful and that being helpful, rather than a distinctive writing style, is what is of chief importance. I do not, at least not consciously, try to write in a style designed to be peculiarly personal. Indeed, the writing I did professionally was meant to be impersonal.